# Show maps with multiple markers in a reveal modal(foundation)

Tags: modal-dialog, maps, zurb-foundation

I've create a map with multiple markes.

Now I'd like to show it in a reveal modal (foundation 6), can someone help me?

I would like to display the google map in a modal reveal, to be visible only when I click on "Open google map".

It seems that what I did does not work properly and I do not understand why.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/x6nqL3po/1388/

```
<div id="map" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
<div><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a></div>

<script>
//Google Maps
    jQuery(function() {
        if ($("#map").length) {
            initMap();
        }
    });

    //initMap
    function initMap() {
       var locations = [
                [
        "Locatie title 1",
        52.147173,
        4.470745,
        "http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/images/marker-icon.png",
        "city 1",
        "Address 1",
        "+38/(071)/123/45/67"
    ],
    [
        "Locatie title 2",
        52.166245,
        4.51764,
        "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
        "city 2",
        "",
        "+38/(071)/123/45/67"
    ],
    [
        "Locatie title 4",
        52.126607,
        4.619146,
        "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
        "",
        "Address 4",
        "+38 (071) 123-45-67"
    ],
];
    ];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 9,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.159393,4.673784),

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var lat = locations[i][1];
            var lng = locations[i][2];
            var pin = locations[i][3];
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: pin,
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", (function(marker, i) {
                var title = (locations[i][0] !== undefined) ? locations[i][0] : '';
                var city = (locations[i][4] !== undefined) ? locations[i][4] : '';
                var address = (locations[i][5] !== undefined) ? locations[i][5] : '';
                var html = ( (title !== '') ? "<h5>" + title + "</h5>" : title ) + ( (city !== '') ? "<h6>" + city + "</h6>" : city ) + ( (address !== '') ? "<p>" + address + "</p>" : address ) ;

                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setOptions({
                        content:html
                    });                 
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                };
                //auto center map
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());  
            })(marker, i)
        );
        }
    }
        function load() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0599153,31.2620199,13),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in first place you must change the `id` of modal container, this should be the same that `data-reveal-id` on the link (now one is "MyModal" and the other is "map").

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Open google map</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
```

In your jsfiddle file it seems not loading foundation.css, foundation.js, foundation.reveal.js and jquery, these are necessary as indicated on [Reveal Modal Foundation docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html) (Using the Javascript section)

You can check a updated working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/x6nqL3po/1488/